# How can I define env variable value during the release phase in Azure?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Nx monorepo project set up. I want to set some environment variables to use throughout my app. I'm looking for a solution where I can define a value for these variables during the release process to each environment (QA, Test, Dev).
Example:
`NX_API_URL` is my environment variable in my .env file.
If I release to QA env the variable should be `NX_API_URL=api-url-qa.com`.
If I release to Test env the variable should be `NX_API_URL=api-url-test.com`

I have found solutions during the build process but that's not going to work, it needs to be at the release phase. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want to create your release using Buils Pipelines(Yaml) or using Release Pipelines(Classic)?

Comment: I have a yaml build pipeline that creates the build artifact. The artifact is then released to different environments

Answer (score 0):

If the file that you'd like to modify during the deployment process is either XML or JSON you can define the URLs as tokens and use standard 'FileTransform' task to replace them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/file-transform-v2?view=azure-pipelines

For more details regarding file transformation please refer to documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic

If none of the links above will help you with this, then I'd suggest to create PS script to do whatever modifications are required, like adding a line after specific line definition: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fabc9790-0ffe-43b2-9d6b-bc483cd28bb6/add-line-to-a-text-file-just-after-a-specific-line-with-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell